# Is there a way to view the console output instead of boot logo, while my RHEL 6.2 machine boots up?

Tags: linux, boot, rhel, console, startup

My company provided laptop has RHEL6.2, with lot of programs to start up automatically, which makes the boot up process slow.

While the machine boots up, there is the boring RHEL logo on the screen for a long time.

Instead is there way to view the console, while my machine boots up? The console log would at least keep scrolling and won't be as monotonous! :)

**Edit:**

My laptop has [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) disk encryption. So after grub screen, LUKS asks for the disk password and then the RHEL logo keeps rotating for a long time!

Answer (score 3):

Check your `/etc/default/grub` file. You should see a line like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"
```

Change that to :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"
```

then, as root, run

```
update-grub
```

---

UPDATE:
     I just realized that RHEL6.2 uses grub instead of grub2. That is why you are missing the `/etc/default/grub` file. What you should do then, is edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, look for the line that boots your kernel, it should be something like:

```
menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 3.6-lfs-SVN-20121002" {
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.6-lfs-SVN-20121002 root=/dev/sda2 splash quiet
}
```

Change that to :

```
menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 3.6-lfs-SVN-20121002" {
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.6-lfs-SVN-20121002 root=/dev/sda2 nosplash
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't seem to have /etc/default/grub. Looks like my laptop is specially configured... Anything else I could try?

Comment: See my updated answer @Curious.

Comment: sorry, but I do not see such entries in my grub.cfg, seems like my IT folks have configured my laptop in some special way...

Comment: @Curious do you have a `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file? Could you also give me the exact version of grub you are using (e.g. `grub-install -v`).

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will switch between Plymouth and the console.

Comment: I discovered this accidentally! Was looking for a solution that persists and does not require Esc!